# Alfresco - Disable LDAP Group Synchronization

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-ldap

In our project's client is having LDAP with no Groups configuration.
They're only have single flat Users directory/configuration.
Hence I want to disable Group synchronization, but have no clean and precise answer for this situation.

I have similar problem with this:
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/alfresco-32-ldap-user-sync

Does Alfresco support disable group synchronization? If so, how to achieve this.

Thanks,

[bayu]

Comment: Point the groups sync at an empty part of the LDAP tree, so it just syncs nothing?

Comment: It works with some WARN such as complaints about GID.

From the tomcat log the synchronization was success:
`2016-09-08 11:19:59,603  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Processed 222 entries out of 222. 100% complete. Rate: 13 per second. 0 failures detected.`

But when check it from Admin Tools > Users, it's still not updated or LDAP users not updated (properly). Any hints?

Comment: SOLVED: because ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName set to null. I set it null because the configuration doesn't have "last name" parameter. Then I fill it up same with "first name"; and it works. Thanks.